# Error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`

Tags: pallet, pallet-contracts

I am building a solo chain from [Substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template), I have made some changes to switch from PoA to PoS just like [this repo](https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/POA-to-POS). Now, I am trying to add `pallet-contracts` on the runtime. I added the following in the `Cargo.toml` file:

```
pallet-contracts = { version = "23.0.0", package = "pallet-contracts", default-features = false }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { version = "27.0.0", package = "pallet-contracts-primitives", default-features = false }


[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    ...,
    "pallet-contracts/std",
    "pallet-contracts-primitives/std",

]
```

Now when I try to implement the Config trait for the Contracts pallet I add the following code:

```
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    /// The safest default is to allow no calls at all.
    ///
    /// Runtimes should whitelist dispatchables that are allowed to be called from contracts
    /// and make sure they are stable. Dispatchables exposed to contracts are not allowed to
    /// change because that would break already deployed contracts. The `Call` structure itself
    /// is not allowed to change the indices of existing pallets, too.
    type CallFilter = Nothing;
    type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
    type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
    type DefaultDepositLimit = DefaultDepositLimit;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 5];
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
    type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 123 * 1024 }>;
    type MaxStorageKeyLen = ConstU32<128>;
    type UnsafeUnstableInterface = ConstBool<false>;
    type MaxDebugBufferLen = ConstU32<{ 2 * 1024 * 1024 }>;
    type RuntimeHoldReason = RuntimeHoldReason;
    #[cfg(not(feature = "runtime-benchmarks"))]
    type Migrations = ();
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    type Migrations = pallet_contracts::migration::codegen::BenchMigrations;
    type MaxDelegateDependencies = ConstU32<32>;
    type CodeHashLockupDepositPercent = CodeHashLockupDepositPercent;
    type Debug = ();
    type Environment = ();
}
```

But adding this code gave me this error (among others), which I am not sure why it happens:

```
 error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `node_template_runtime` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/MainGitReposBlockchain/Devolved_AI_Blockchain/NodeMainTemplate/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-2d4b947295faf0f7.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/MainGitReposBlockchain/Devolved_AI_Blockchain/NodeMainTemplate/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-6ce5327a26e230a7.rmeta
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you share the whole Cargo.toml? It looks there is some error with the imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import pallet-contract in `runtime/Cargo.toml` ( should be the same branch)

```
pallet-contracts = {git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0", default-features = false }
```

Remember that you should add `std` features:

https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/proof-of-stake-node-template/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml#L76

`pallet-contracts/std`

`pallet-contracts-primitives/std`

You can check this reference:

https://github.com/truongngoctan91/add_pallet_contracts/tree/main